# How to generate a hash code from three longs

Tags: java, hashcode, hash-code-uniqueness

I have a HashMap with coordinates as keys.

Coordinates have 3 longs holding the x, y and z coordinate. (Coordinate is and needs to be a custom class, the coordinates need to be longs).

Now i want to be able to access e.g. the field [5, 10, 4] by doing: `hashMap.get(new Coordinate(5, 10, 4))`.

I have implemented the equals method but that is not enough since apparently i need to provide an implementation for hashCode as well. So my question is **how do i generate an unique hashCode from three longs?**.

Additional: Using a hash generator from an external library is not option.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Joshua Bloch tells you how to write equals and hashCode for your Coordinate class in [chapter 3](http://java.sun.com/developer/Books/effectivejava/Chapter3.pdf) of his "Effective Java".

Like this:

```
public class Coordinate
{
    private long x;
    private long y;
    private long z;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o)
    {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        Coordinate that = (Coordinate) o;

        if (x != that.x) return false;
        if (y != that.y) return false;
        if (z != that.z) return false;

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode()
    {
        int result = (int) (x ^ (x >>> 32));
        result = 31 * result + (int) (y ^ (y >>> 32));
        result = 31 * result + (int) (z ^ (z >>> 32));
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for the interesting link, just that if i calculate it that way, the integer has a good chance of flowing over, is that the way it's used to be?

Comment: Now, it won't flow over.  You'll return a meaningful int.

Comment: But i take long1 = Integer.MAX_VALUE, long2 = 5 and long3 = 10, the the result will at some point flow over no? at least when i do result * 37? I'm just trying to fully understand it, excuse me if i'm being stubborn

Comment: @Samuel, a hashcode is intended to be evenly distibuted and pseudo-random.  It is a hash function and is not intended to be unique. ;)

Comment: Okay thank you a lot, i'll probably use the book for more than just this :)

Answer (score 5):

This is an old question, but if anyone bumps into it, now there is an easier way to do it:

```
@Override 
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(x, y, z);
}
```

Comment: @Carlos: A standard language feature, that is being used by millions of programs, is always easier and safer than writing your own :)

Comment: Your proposal (x + y + z) will lead to collisions for (0 + 0 + 1) or (1 + 0 + 0) or (0 + 1 + 0). Using a standard feature of a language, which has been developed, verified, tested, and retested millions of times, is always safer.

Answer (score 4):

In Java, the standard `hashCode()` method returns `int`, which is 32 bits.

The `long` datatype is 64 bits. Therefore, three `long`s means 192 bits of information, which of course cannot be uniquely mapped into just 32 bits of hash value by *any* hash function.

However, a `HashMap` will not require unique hashing, it will simply handle the collisions when they occur.

A naive way would be to build the string, i.e. "x,y,z", then hash the string.

You could also try just XOR:ing the values together:

```
int hashCode()
{
  return (int) (x ^ y ^ z);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> how do i generate an unique hashCode
>   from three longs?

You don't need to. Hash codes are not required to be unique.

Answer (score 1):

You should realize there is a difference between a hashcode and the unique key to be used in a HashMap.

The hashcode for your Coordinate class does not have to be unique at all...

A good solution for the hashcode would be:

```
(int)(x ^ (x >> 32) ^ y ^ (y >> 32) ^ z ^ (z >> 32));
```

Wich is the XOR of the two halves of each of the longs XOR-ed together.