# Smarter way to make a key for lookup

Tags: objective-c

I have a process that is taking longer than I think it should.  When I run Instruments, it shows that the method I use to create a key for an `NSDictionary` lookup is taking about 25% of the overall time.  The end result is, if I can optimize this key generation, I could save several seconds.  The string gets generated as follows:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld_%.0f_%.0f_%d%@", (long)zoomLevel, mapPoint.x, mapPoint.y, dataType, suffix];
```

I feel that parsing the format string is the pain point here, but I'm not sure how else to smash these variables together to create a key.

***EDIT***

I need to generate the exact same key when given the exact same inputs.  So no UUID, timestamp, etc.

Comment: Is adding time in miliseconds to your String helpful? So it will be unique

Comment: Use `NSUUID`.  That's what it's for.

Comment: do you need to be able to regenerate this key or does it simply need to be unique? what are you using the key for? can you structure the data differently?

Comment: No ready-for-use solution at hand but check 
[How to generate a hash code from three longs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5730149/how-to-generate-a-hash-code-from-three-longs) and [Mapping two integers to one, in a unique and deterministic way](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/919612/mapping-two-integers-to-one-in-a-unique-and-deterministic-way) and also you may google smth like "hash three numbers".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sprintf` instead of `[NSString stringWithFormat:...]`, which performs [much faster](http://blog.foundry376.com/2013/01/stringwithformat-is-slow-really-slow/).

```
char cString[256];
sprintf(cString, "%ld_%.0f_%.0f_%d%s", (long)zoomLevel, mapPoint.x, mapPoint.y, dataType, suffix.UTF8String];
NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:cString];
```

Just be sure that you allocate enough space for your string when declaring your `char` array.

Comment: This solution is about 1.6x faster.  Nice!